# How to call kaltura video in jw player

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, jwplayer, kaltura

I am using **kaltura** server for video trans-coding. And i want to use **JW player** to display video. 
If i open kaltura video url in browser it works fine. and also when i add any mp4 file or youtube video url in **JW player** it is also working fine. But i want to use **kaltura** videos in JW player.

Please find the code which i am using here:-

```
jwplayer('myElement').setup({
'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
        'file': '/p/101/sp/10100/serveFlavor/flavorId/0_evyl5mbk/seekFrom/-1',
        'image': 'http://sim01.in.com/cb544f794c1f6a0fd324c25bcf1deca9_ls_xl.jpg',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '640',
        'height': '480'
});
```

Can you guys please let me know how can I use **JW player** for **kaltura** videos.

Comment: What sort of file is - /p/101/sp/10100/serveFlavor/flavorId/0_evyl5mbk/seekFrom/-1 ?

Comment: It is a url where kaltura saved the different flavors of videos files. It can be like http://www.example.com/p/101/sp/10100/serveFlavor/flavorId/0_evyl5mbk/seekFrom/-1

Comment: Yeah, that isn't going to work, it has to be the direct path to the video file, singular, not a list.

Answer (score 3):

We can play Kaltura videos using JWPlayer.

This is not the way to call using JWPlayer.  Try this, it should works well

```
    jwplayer('myElement').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
            'file': 'http://yourKalturaServerIp/p/101/sp/10100/serveFlavor/entryId/flavorId/play.mp4 or whatever the format',
            'image': 'http://sim01.in.com/cb544f794c1f6a0fd324c25bcf1deca9_ls_xl.jpg',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'width': '640',
            'height': '480'
    });
```

Also you can use playManifest API, it is a good sign always to play them from Kaltura.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

JW Player supports either videos that you host yourself, or videos provided by YouTube. There is no support for other providers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use playable URL to play video as mp4 file

```
"file": 'Your Kaltura domain'+'/p/'+partnerId+ '/sp/'+"subpartnerId"+"/playManifest/entryId/"+entryId + "/format/url/video.mp4"
```